# Google Groups thinks a member I want to add is already a member

Tags: google-groups

I've just started a new Google Group to replace an old email list that proved unreliable.  An email address I'd like to add as a member is being rejected because Google Groups thinks it's already a member.  The address does not show up on the members list nor the outstanding invitations list.

Two potential reasons:

1. The owner of the address in question is already a member of the list, but with a different email address.  He wants to add his second address as well, but that his first address is a member already is somehow preventing this.  However, other members of the group have already successfully added two different email addresses to the group.
2. The email address for the old, unreliable list is currently a member of the Google Group.  The email address I'm having trouble adding is the owner of the old list, and that is preventing his being added.

Both potential reasons seem fairly far fetched to me.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Go to Google Groups Settings > Pending Requests. The person you sent to the request to probably never answered the invitation. Delete it and resend a new one. This just happened to me.

Answer (score 1):

The first potential reason : 
the two involved email addresses are both listed in the users 
Google account in myaccount.google.com/email .

Answer (score 0):

I just found the reason. The ones that don't show up in the members list are the ones that were imported through a CSV file.
I tried to change name and showed up as a member of the group ... then I had to return it to its original name.

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]! Please delete your other answer, as it doesn't really answer the question.